# Add HTML table to Outlook Body

Tags: html, vb.net, outlook, formatting, html-table

I am trying to use **`Outlook`** to send mails and I need to add **`HTML table`** inside my `Outlook body`.

This is what I have done but it is trying to add the **`HTMLtags`** but not the **`design`**.

```
Dim body As String
objOutlook = CType(CreateObject("Outlook.Application"), Outlook.Application)
objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem)
Dim strb As New StringBuilder
strb.Append("<table width='600px' align='center' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' style='border-top:5px solid white;'")
strb.Append("<tr><td>S.No</td><td>AccountID</td><td>ChargeEntryControl</td><td>PaymentPostingControl</td></tr></table>")
body = "Hi,
body += strb.ToString
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the full code I used, and it displays the email as I believe you want.

```
    Dim body As String
    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Dim objEmail As Object
    objOutlook = CType(CreateObject("Outlook.Application"), Outlook.Application)
    objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem)
    Dim strb As New StringBuilder
    strb.Append("<table width='600px' align='center' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' style='border-top:5px solid white;'")
    strb.Append("<tr><td>S.No</td><td>AccountID</td><td>ChargeEntryControl</td><td>PaymentPostingControl</td></tr></table>")
    body = "Hi,"
    body += strb.ToString
    objEmail.htmlbody = body
    objEmail.display()
```

Comment: @APrough-I have set it but its of no use :(

Comment: See above for the full code listing I used to get the email to show properly.